# Exclude Nexus 7 from supported devices

Tags: android, filter

I have an application that currently does not support Nexus 7 very well. So I would like to exclude it from my supported device list. But I do want to make my app available to Galaxy Nexus. But how can I do that? I think both are large display size and hdpi density if I am not mistaken. So how can I filter out Nexus 7 but keep Galaxy Nexus. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is off topic. Normally device filtering is done in Android manifest file. As Darshan replied, it can be done with tvdpi in manifest but can also be done in the dev console. Please reconsider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the Nexus 7 is a `large`, `tvdpi` device while the Galaxy Nexus is `normal` and `xhdpi`.  Still, I think you're right to want to exclude as few devices as possible; it's probably best not to  rule out `large` or `tvdpi` devices across the board.

Thankfully, you can exclude devices from distribution through the Play Store on a per-model basis:

1. Go to the Developer Console.
2. Scroll down to "Supported Devices" and click "Show devices".
3. Scroll to or search for "Nexus 7".
4. Press "Exclude".
5. Press "Done".

Once you get the kinks worked out on the Nexus 7, just go back in and re-enable it there.

Comment: Thanks, Darshan! Didn't think it's so simple. :-)